# How to save values to an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

Still trying to write a a C++ program that can be used to determine grades at the end of the semester. For each student, who is identified by an integer number between 1 and 60, four examination grades must be kept. Additionally, two final grade averages must be computed. The first grade average is simply the average of all four grades. The second grade average is computed by weighting the four grades as follows: the first grade gets a weight of 0.2, the second grade gets a weight of 0.3, the third grade a weight of 0.3, and the fourth grade a weight of 0.2; that is computed as:
0.2 * grade1 + 0.3 * grade2+ 0.3* grade3 + 0.2 * grade4
Using this information, you are to construct a 60 X 7 two dimensional array, in which the first column is used for the student number, the next four columns for the grades, and the last two columns for the computed final grades. The output of the program should be a display of the data in the completed array.

Your program should print the grade matrix ( table gridline not required), including the averages. Then it should calculate the mean and standard deviation for both averages for the class and print the results.

This is what I have so far, but I don't know how to calculate the standard deviation without putting the individual points into the program. Help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int grade_Calc(int sg[][5]); //initiates function grade_Calc

int main()
{
int student_grades[5][5] =
{
    {1, 100, 100, 100, 100}, //inputs an array of students 1-5's grades
    {2, 100, 0, 100, 0},
    {3, 82, 94, 73, 86},
    {4, 64, 74, 84, 94},
    {5, 94, 84, 74, 64},
    };

grade_Calc(student_grades); //passes array student_grades into function grade_Calc
return 0;
}


int grade_Calc(int sg[][5])
{
int sum_for_avg = 0; //initializes sum_for_avg (adds up students scores for taking the mean)
double weighted_grade = 0.0; //initializes weighted_grade (uses formula 0.2 * grade1 + 0.3 * grade2+ 0.3* grade3 + 0.2 * grade4)
double simple_avg = 0.0; //initializes simple_avg (arithmetic mean)
double class_mean1 = 0.0;
double class_mean1_sum = 0.0;
double class_mean2 = 0.0;
double class_mean2_sum = 0.0;
double standardDeviation1 = 0.0;
double standardDeviation2 = 0.0;


cout << "Stdnt" << "\t" << "Grd1" << "\t" << "Grd2" << "\t" << "Grd3" << "\t" << "Grd4" << "\t" << "Avg1" << "\t" << "Avg2" << endl; //outputs column headings
for (int r = 0; r < 5; r++) //goes through array rows
{
    for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++) //goes through array columns
    {
        cout << sg[r][c] << "\t\t"; //outputs array elements with 2 tabs between each element

        if (c != 0) //ensures that the student number isn't included in the calculations
        {
            sum_for_avg += sg[r][c]; //adds up students scores for taking the mean

            if ((c == 1) || (c == 4)) //if-else that calculates weighted_grade (uses formula 0.2 * grade1 + 0.3 * grade2+ 0.3* grade3 + 0.2 * grade4)
            {
                weighted_grade += (0.2 * sg[r][c]);
            }
            else
            {
                weighted_grade += (0.3 * sg[r][c]);
            }
        }
    }

    simple_avg = (sum_for_avg / 4.0); //calculates simple_avg (arithmetic mean)

    cout << "\t" << simple_avg << "\t" << weighted_grade; //outputs simple_avg in Avg1 column and weighted_grade in Avg2 column

    class_mean1_sum += simple_avg;
    class_mean1 = class_mean1_sum/5;
    standardDeviation1 = sqrt(pow(100-class_mean1,2) +
                             pow(50-class_mean1,2) +
                             pow(83.75-class_mean1,2) +
                             pow(79-class_mean1,2) +
                             pow(79-class_mean1,2)/ 5.0);

    class_mean2_sum += weighted_grade;
    class_mean2 = class_mean2_sum/5;
    standardDeviation2 = sqrt(pow(100-class_mean1,2) +
                              pow(50-class_mean1,2) +
                              pow(83.7-class_mean1,2) +
                              pow(79-class_mean1,2) +
                              pow(79-class_mean1,2)/ 5.0);

    sum_for_avg = 0;
    weighted_grade = 0.0;
    cout << endl;
    }

cout << endl;
cout << "The class average for Avg1 is " << class_mean1;

cout << endl;
cout << "The standard deviation for Avg1 is " << standardDeviation1;

cout << endl;
cout << "The class average for Avg 2 is " << class_mean2;

cout << endl;
cout << "The standard deviation for Avg2 is " << standardDeviation2 << endl;

return 0;

}
```

Comment: *"how to calculate the standard deviation without putting the individual points into the program"* - what do you mean? Aren't the required data points already in the program, in the `student_grades` array? Your calculation looks bizarre though: the standard deviation should be calculated by looping over the data points, summing the squared deviation from the average you've calculated, dividing by the number of samples then taking the square root, but you're hardcoding values: e.g. the `50` in `50-class_mean1` - where did that come from?

Comment: How could I do that? I hardcoded, because I didn't know how to do otherwise. I want to save those numbers that I hardcoded (which are calculated elsewhere in the program) to an array so that I can access them and calculate standard deviation.

Comment: Oh... well, why not `push_back` the numbers to a `std::vector<double>` or `std::vector<int>` depending on the accuracy you want? For the student scores - if you need to e.g. load them from a file later - you could use `std::vector<std::array<int, 5>> student_scores;`....

Comment: Okay, I'm trying that now! Thank you :)

Comment: @AlexisJ. Maybe you should split up this material, it seems like you have multiple questions 'How to save values to an array?' and 'I don't know how to calculate the standard deviation without putting the individual points into the program. Help?'. That way you'll get better help.